# Change of basis of tangent space Lee, Smooth Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, change-of-basis, tangent-spaces

I have a question about the passage in chapter 11 of Lee's smooth manifold:
[image]

[image]

So if I am understanding this correctly, the matrix for the change of basis for the tangent space takes in vectors from our old coordinate and gives us vectors in terms of our new coordinate. Now traditionally (i,j) stands for (row, column) but I wrote the matrix out and this is impossible if that were the case. It only makes sense if (i,j) is actually (column, row). Is that the case here?

Comment: Sometimes it could be convenient to think of the upper indexes to parametrize rows and lower to parametrize columns. Then, 11.6 expresses the identity of two column vectors (whose rows are parametrized by $j$) so that on the right the matrix $\partial\tilde x^j / \partial x^i$ has row index $j$ and column index $i$ and acts by left multiplication on the column vector with rows indexed by $i$ and entries $v_i$. Similarly, 11.7 expresses the identity of two row vectors, whose columns are parametrized by $i$

Comment: @Bill maybe you arranged $v^i$ and $\tilde{v}^j$ as column vectors. But then $i$ is the column index for the Jacobian matrix, in order for the product of it by $v^i$ to work properly. It follows that $j$ must be the row index of the Jacobian matrix agreeing with the fact that for the result of the product $\tilde{v}^j$ $j$ is a row index.

Comment: So it seems like it is a convention in differential geometry that upper index is usually the rows and lower index the columns . I wasn’t aware this was standard .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, if we write a matrix $A$ in the form $A = (a_{ij})$, then the first index $i$ denotes the row number in which we find the entry $a_{ij}$ and the second index $j$ denotes the column number. However, we can equally well write $A = (a_{ji})$ or $A = (a_{kl})$ or something else - simply because the two index variables do not have an intrinsic meaning.

To emphasize it again, the essential point is that the first index always denotes the row number and the second index always denotes the column number. This is of course merely a convention, but it is a *commonly accepted convention* and no author would be well-advised to ignore it. Also Lee complies with this convention. Perhaps it is a bit unusual that he uses the "$A = (a_{ji})$" notation, but it is completely legit.

Have a look at the computation of the matrix of $F_* : T_p\mathbb R^n \to  T_{F(p)}\mathbb R^m$ of a smooth map $F : U \to  V$ in terms of the
standard coordinate bases, where $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ and $V \subset \mathbb R^m$  are open. Lee obtains the formula
$$F_*\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \mid_p = \frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\mid_{F(p)}$$
(recall the sum convention). This gives as the matrix of $F_*$
$$\mathcal M(F_*) =  \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{\partial F^1}{\partial x^1}(p) \dots \dfrac{\partial F^1}{\partial x^n}(p)  \\ ... \\ \dfrac{\partial F^m}{\partial x^1}(p) \dots \dfrac{\partial F^m}{\partial x^n}(p) \end{pmatrix} \tag{1}$$
which is the usual Jacobian matrix of $F$. He writes it in the form
$$\mathcal M(F_*) = \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}(p) \end{pmatrix} \tag{2}$$
If we only look at $(2)$ we see that the entries of $\mathcal M(F_*)$ have two indices $i$ and $j$, but it is indeed not obvious which of $i$ and $j$ refer to rows and columns, respectively. We can even regard it as misleading if we assume the "$A = (a_{ij})$" notation.

However $(1)$ makes clear that Lee means
$$\mathcal M(F_*) = (a_{ji})$$
with $a_{ji} = \dfrac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}(p) $.